# Facebook sdk console error

Tags: facebook

Im trying to add this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin

All okey , everything works but it shows error in console.

[image]

How to fix it?
 Didn't find any information in google.

```
    /* Facebook messenger plugin  */

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '**',
            autoLogAppEvents: false,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v4.0'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

code used.

Comment: Your last bracket is to much?

Comment: Nop its not the problem. ;/

Comment: It is not the problem because you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
  // ...do something...
})();



(function(d, s, id){ 
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    } 
    js = d.createElement(s); 
    js.id = id; js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";    
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: I know how function works. The question was how to fix this error.

Comment: If you removed the { and the code is still logging this error than I suggest you to check or deactivate third party js code. And if this isn't helping then check https://developers.facebook.com/status/dashboard/ for issues or open a ticket in developer.facebook.com